# Cannot resolve symbol 'github' from Dotenv dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm getting the following error when trying to use the `Dotenv` dependency

> Cannot resolve symbol 'github'

I get the error above in this line of code:
**Java class**

`import io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.Dotenv;`

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.cdimascio</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-dotenv</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In my terminal I ran:

`mvn package`

`mvn dependency:resolve`

`mvn clean install`

I was following these tutorials:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1HsGbTZObQ
- https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-java
- https://github.com/cdimascio/dotenv-java

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>PayPalService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PayPalService</name>
    <description>PayPal Service project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.cdimascio</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-dotenv</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220924</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm new to Java and Maven and based on my small knowledge those commands above should help me install dependencies. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you add your entire pom.xml?

Comment: @Reg I have added the pom.xml

Comment: did you find a solution for that?